# Python, Selenium, scrol?

Tags: python, selenium, прокрутка

Есть функция которая вытаскивает ссылки из динамического сайта.

```
def pars_urls():

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://**-**.com/Results')
sleep(2)
prev_height = 0
while True:
    respons = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respons, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find_all('a', target='_self')
    with open('soup.txt', 'a') as read_html:
        for url in block:
            a = 'здесь url сайта' + url.get('href')
            read_html.write(a+'\n')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000)")
    sleep(2)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == prev_height:
        print('Достигли конца')
        break
    prev_height = new_height
```

вот тут

```
if new_height == prev_height:
        print('Достигли конца')
        break
    prev_height = new_height
```

блок кода которая заканчивает скрол, вроде бы все логично. Узнаем высоту страницы, проверяем её первичной высотой если равно то заканчиваем скрол и закрываем браузер, если нет то перезаписываем первичный и по новой. Но оно не работает. Она скролит почти до конца, там остается еще немного не открывшихся ссылок и закрывает программу. Как вы говорите программе что она уже дошла до конца страницы, хватит её скролить завязывай.